# Why wont my code execute both in Terminal & on spyder IDE?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, python-3.5, spyder

I'm analysing this data set using ML techniques in Python3.5 on sypder IDE (Ubuntu OS) and my program is supposed to work fine (matches perfectly with [tutorial program](https://pythonprogramming.net/scikit-learn-sklearn-machine-learning-data-analysis-python-pandas-tutorial/)) but it does nothing when run - nothing gets printed or returned. The console of spyder IDE displays the following and does nothing after that:

```
runfile('/media/username/Laniakea/Projects/Training/SPYDER/classifier/sk_classifier.py', wdir='/media/username/Laniakea/Projects/Training/SPYDER/classifier')
```

I used to get this when a new program starts to run, and the output would follow but here, I get nothing. My program:

```
from sklearn import svm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_pickled_train2 = pd.read_pickle('df_train.pickle')
df_pickled_test2 = pd.read_pickle('df_test.pickle')

df_pickled_train2_y = pd.read_pickle('df_train_y.pickle')
df_pickled_test2_y = pd.read_pickle('df_test_y.pickle')

X = np.array(df_pickled_train2)
y = np.array(df_pickled_train2_y)

X_test = np.array(df_pickled_test2)
y_test = np.array(df_pickled_test2_y)

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X,y.ravel())

print(clf.score(X_test,y_test))
print("Done")
```

If you want to see how the pickles get created (and this program runs fine - it even prints out the final line "Done" or anything else I want it to print):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_train = pd.read_csv('Adult-Incomes/train-labelled-final-variables-condensed-coded-countries-removed-unlabelled-income-to-the-left-relabelled-copy.csv')
df_test = pd.read_csv('Adult-Incomes/test-final-variables-cleaned-coded-copy-unlabelled.csv')

df_train_no_y = df_train.drop('Income',1)
df_test_no_y = df_test.drop(df_test.columns[0],axis=1)

df_train_y = pd.DataFrame(df_train['Income'])
df_train_y.to_pickle('df_train_y.pickle')

df_test_y = df_test[df_test.columns[0]]
df_test_y.to_pickle('df_test_y.pickle')

df_test_no_y.to_pickle('df_test.pickle')
df_train_no_y.to_pickle('df_train.pickle')

print ("DONE")
```

PS: Even if run from the Terminal, it simply executes but does nothing. Meaning, in terminal, the cursor would go to the next line and print out the output before prompting for another command right, but here, it simply stays there. It's not even hung, as the cursor blinks and computer is not hung. It feels like, the code somehow sends the executor into a limbo.

P.P.S: I even suspected that it is running a complex algo, genuinely requiring time and left it over night. Nothing happened even then.

Can someone tell me why my program wont run or display anything?

Comment: Sorry but what do you expect it to display? You only have some print statements, but no graphics nor anything different in your code :-/

Comment: It's supposed to print `print(clf.score(X_test,y_test))
print("Done")` and secondly, it doesn't even stop executing. After a successful execution of a code or any code for that matter, the console should prompt me for the next command (as I'm sure you might have noticed in Ubuntu terminal or windows command prompt or console of any IDE that you may use). But it doesn't and just hangs there in limbo.

Comment: What's your Spyder version? And, are you using the Python or IPython console in Spyder?

Comment: IPython console

Comment: And your Spyder version?

Comment: Spyder 3.0.2; Python 3.5.2 64bits, Qt 5.7.0, PyQt5 5.7 on Linux

Comment: Please open an issue in Spyder's issue tracker: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues along with the files and data necessary to run your code above. I really can't say what's happening in your case.